# Given $T(n) = \sum_{i = 0}^{\log n} i 2^i$, what is $O(T(n))$?

Tags: asymptotics

I'm trying to perform an asymptotic analysis on a function:

$T(n) = \sum_{i = 0}^{\log n} i 2^i$

The above expression came about when I began with:

$T(n) = \sum_{i = 0}^{\log n} 2^i \log (2^i)$

Is there a tight, closed-form expression for $O(T(n))$?

Comment: Well, $T \in O(T)$ -- but what is it you really want? What have you tried and where did you get stuck? Hint: [there's a well-known identity for such sums](https://www.tug.org/texshowcase/cheat.pdf). (Note that this is a pure mathematics question. What is its relation to CS, if any?)

Comment: I was looking for a tight upper bound on T(n) purely in terms of n. The below answer got me to my solution. I suppose you're right that, the way this was posed, it is a pure mathematics question. However, this expression came directly from asymptotic analysis of a particular algorithm I was working on. I assumed that the CS stackexchange would have more direct experience with sums of this form, since they seem to pop up all the time.

Comment: We appreciate if the question exposes the CS connection. :) As for your phrasing, it's still not expressive; the original expression *is* "purely in terms of $n$". I think what you are looking for is a *closed form* of the sum -- but that you don't need asymptotics for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to calculate the sum. The first way is to write it as $$\sum_{i=1}^{\log n} \sum_{k=1}^{i}2^{i}.$$

You change the order of sum and the calculation is the sum of geometric series.

Another way is to write it as $f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{\log n} x^{i}$, and find the $xf`(x)|_{x=2}$, again a sum of geometric series.

Comment: Can you explain how you change the order of the sums in the first approach?

Comment: Think is like an integral. you have that $k\leq i$ and $1\leq i \leq logn$ so it will tranform to $\sum_{k=1}^{logn} \sum_{i=k}^{logn}$.

Comment: Ah, I have it now! Thanks a lot for your help!